# multiple threads using threadsafe collection

Tags: java, multithreading

i am not understanding how below code snippet can be made thread safe.

```
class MapUser {
    Map<String,Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Integer>

    public void addToMap(String str, Integer val){
        if(checkMagicString(str)){
            map.put(str,val);
        }
    }

    private boolean checkMagicString(String str){
        //some logic to check Magic
        //this logic involved operation on the String parameter str i.e. subString,toCharArray etc
    }
}
```

Note the method addToMap is called by multiple threads concurrently. I want to make sure that thread safety is maintained. By using ConcurrentHashMap I can ensure that threads will add the values to it safely.

However I am not understanding how method checkMagicString(String str) can remain thread safe? Is the only way to do it to make it synchronized? Or should the caller method addToMap be made synchronized? 
Please note that I am not accessing the map inside checkMagicString method.

Comment: I assume that you are accessing the `map` inside of `checkMagicString`?  If not then you are fine.  If you are then please edit your post to show that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you do make `checkMagicString` atomic, it will not make the sequence

```
if(checkMagicString(str)){
   map.put(str,val);
}
```

atomic, since a thread can be interrupted between the `if` check and the `map.put` call and thus you might end up with two threads inserting the same string. You need to lock the entire sequence to be safe.

**Edit**: If the above is acceptable behavior (i.e. two threads inserting the same key and overwriting the value) and `checkMagicString` does not operate on shared state then your code is fine as it is.

Comment: It really depends on what checkMagicString is doing. As long as it does not access the map, the 2 operations don't have to be atomic to maintain thread safety.

Comment: @assylias: The two operations no, but the sequence should be, as I assume he does not want two threads putting the same string.

Comment: do you mean by using synchronized the addToMap method? If that is required then what's benefit of multithreading here?

Comment: @Tudor If checkMagicString does not access the map, nothing prevents 2 consecutive calls to put the same string into the map twice. So making the 2 operations atomic does not make a difference (but adds unnecessary contention).

Comment: @assylias: I agree, I was stating that regardless of `checkMagicString`s atomicity, the resulting sequence will not be atomic.

Comment: @Tudor I understand your point and your statement is factually true, but I'm saying that the actual question (is this thread safe?) can't be answered without knowing what that method is doing.

Comment: @Harshil Mehta: The question is: assume a thread wants to insert a key and a value into the map. If another thread comes and wants to insert the same key and a different value, the new value will overwrite the previous one. Is this acceptable?

Comment: @assylias: I have a feeling the check method involves checking if the string already exists in the map...

Comment: @assylias, the method checkMagicString does not involve checking if the string already exists in the map. it simply find out where the given string is a Magic string or not.

Comment: @Tudor, thanks for proving a definitive answer. do you mean that checkMagicString method can be executed by two threads simultaneously without any problem? I am finding it hard to digest as one thread can change the value of String parameter of the method  which may have been not fully processed by the second thread. isn't it likely?

Comment: @Harshil: Are two threads calling the method with exactly the same string object? Otherwise, each method call exists entirely on the calling thread's private stack, so they cannot interfere with eachother if they only perform computations on private data.

Comment: @Tudor, oh yes, i got what you mean. each thread will have data in its private stack. silly me.. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is an atomic operation the best thing to do in a case like this is to make sure the checkMagicStr atomic, and also use the atomic operations on the map:

```
boolean done = false;
while(!done) {
  Integer oldVal = map.get(str);
  if (checkMagicStr(str) {
    if (oldVal != null) {
      done = value == map.replace(str, val, oldVal); // otherwise try again...
    } else {
      done = null == map.putIfAbsent(str, val); // otherwise try again...
    }
  } else {
    done = true; // there's nothing to do...
  }
}
```

you might want to have a limit on that while loop and throw an exception if it's hit since this could run forever on a highly concurrent system. It's not clear from your question why any of this would be necessary though, b/c what you have would be "thread-safe", but maybe this will help anyway.